# My computer has been stuck on this screen for the past 3 hours. Any clues of what I should do?

Tags: boot

Here is my screen where the computer is stuck.

[image: here's the screen I'm talking about]

Comment: Press `Esc` when you get there and tell us what's on the log screen.

Comment: My computer isn't responding to either Esc or the Ctrl+C commands

Comment: That isn't good. Do you remember doing something weird or messing with ubuntu files with `sudo` command?

Comment: Try Alt+Ctrl+Del. It should reboot.

Comment: Not even... Nothing happens